# this.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/r3kfjx6a/

```
let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm')

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()  
  console.log( this.getElementById('email') )
})

<form id="myForm">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Why I can't start from `this` to query inside the form?

Comment: `getElementById` is only available on `document`, not on all other nodes.

Comment: I see........ but where can I read more about this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: there should only be one element with a particular id in the document so no need to go into your form to get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` refers to the form element. As ***`getElementById()` is only available on `document` object***, you can not use `getElementById()` on other element. Try `querySelector()` instead:

```js
let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm')

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()  
  console.log( this.querySelector('#email') )
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this context, `this` is `HTMLFormElement`, not `document`:

```js
let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm')

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(this);
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm')

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()  
  console.log( document.getElementById('email') )
})

<form id="myForm">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```