# Table search showing error: getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter

I'm trying to make a table filter in JS. I think it's pretty much ok but I get this error:

> row[i].getElementById is not a function

I can't understand why this is happening.

ps:added some of the html so you can see why I searched (getElementsByTagName("row"))
The code is too long to put in here so I'm just adding my try in here you can see it all in the Pen.Thank you.

https://codepen.io/Slemook000/pen/NWMqQGB

```
    function Search() {
          var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
          var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
          var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
          var row = table.getElementsByTagName("row");
          console.log(row)
          
          for (i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            var div = row[i].getElementById("search")[0];
            if (div) {
              var txtValue = div.textContent || div.innerText;
              if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                row[i].style.display = "";
              } else {
                row[i].style.display = "none";
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

```
      <div class="grid-x">
      
        <div id="myTable">
   

      <script>
        var myArray = [
       {
          "ID":7978,
          "Name":"Institutional opening",
          
          },
          
          "Room":"Auditorium WINE2WINE - Palaexpo Piano -1",
          "Categories":[
             {
                "Id":5782,
                "Name":"Eventi in fiera"
             },
             {
                "Id":7973,
                "Name":"wine2wine"
             }
          ],
          "Organizers":[
             
          ],
          "Speakers":[
             {
                "Key":"c1997773-c7ba-4d51-9f58-ac2b388aabf8",
                "Name":"Federico Bricolo",
                "Image":null,
                "Description":{
                   
                }
             },
             {
                "Key":"522937b6-237e-4929-80dd-858719022052",
                "Name":"Maurizio Danese",
                "Image":null,
                "Description":{
                   
                }
             }
          ],
          "Partners":[
             
          ],
          "Url":"https://liveshop.vinitaly.com/eventi/institutional-opening/",
          "UpdateDate":"07/08/2022 15:49:48"
       },
       
    ]
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    buildTable(myArray)

        function buildTable(data) {
          var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Riga attuale
            let row = data[i];
            // Inizio template
            let template_row = '';
            // Creo le colonne
            template_row += `<row class="row event filterDiv content">
         
                  <a href="${row.Url}">  
                <div class="columns small-2 ico">
                <img class="focus" src="${row.Image}"/>
                </div> `;
            template_row += `
                <div class="columns small-2 ico">           
      <div class="swiper mySwiper">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          `;

           // Aggiungo una colonna per ogni speaker
            row.Speakers.forEach(speaker => {
              
              template_row +=
                ` <div class="swiper-slide">      

       
      <img class="focus" src="${speaker.Image}">     
               </div> `;
            });
            
            
            
          
                 template_row +=`
                </div></div></div>
                <div class="columns small-8 info" id="search">
                
                <p class="title release-date p2" id="p2"> ${row.StartDate}</p><br><h3 class="room">${row.Room}</h3><br><h2 class="title">${row.Name}</h2>
     </div></div></div>  ` ;

           
           
            // Fine template
            template_row += ` `;
            table.innerHTML += template_row
            const div = document.getElementById("myTable");
            const nodes = div.getElementsByTagName("p");
               if(document.getElementById("p2").classList.contains("title")){
                var p2 = document.getElementById("p2").innerText;
                var c = row.StartDate;
                 
                console.log(c)
                var c_pos = c.indexOf("07");
                 var element = div.getElementsByTagName("row");

                 if (c_pos > -1) {

                    element[i].className += ' cars';
                     
              
                   }
              if(c_pos <= -1){
                  console.log(element)
                  
                  element[i].className += ' animals';            
                    
                }   
            }
           }
          }   
    </script>
```

Comment: Your code is looking for a `<row>` tag, which does not exist. Hence `row[i]` is `undefined`.  To show you the correct approach to take to fix this problem we need to see the relevant HTML - ideally in a working snippet in the question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan then `row.length` would give `0` and not loop - so `row` must be *something*.  `row[i].func()` would also give `cannot read props of undefined` rather than `not a function`.   As noted, need HTML in a snippet to determine cause.

Comment: @freedomn-m very true. Something weird going on here.

Comment: getElementById() is only available on document object, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267000/this-getelementbyid-is-not-a-function

Comment: The code here bears no resemblance to the code in your codepen.  (Well I couldn't find it in the codepen anyway)

Comment: Yes you can find it after the json api and it's too long to put it in here , that's why I modified the code to get a short of it but it ended up looking different @freedomn-m

Comment: In the codepen, there's only one use of `getElementsByTagName("row")` and it doesn't do a `.length` check after.  There's also no reference at all to `myInput`.  Wrong codepen link perhaps?

Comment: Yes I'm just dumb and sorry  this is the right one. In the js part you can find it  https://codepen.io/Slemook000/pen/NWMqQGB

Comment: Change `row[i].getElementById` to `row[i].querySelector("#search")[0]`.   Following code doesn't seem to work, but that seems to be what you're after.